# SonarQube: No C++ metrics and issues for a multilanguage project containing both C++ and Java

Tags: sonarqube, multilingual, sonar-runner

After using sonar since a while with different projects for each language, I am now trying the new capability of having a multi-language (C++ and Java) and multi-module project (with SonarQube 4.4 using solar-runner).

However, most of the results generated (Metrics, Issues) concern only Java, while few parts (Useless code, profile) is also covering C++.

While looking at the log, I notice that although C++ language is detected, the related C++ sensors are not called:

```
-------------  Scan cg
18:38:45.607 INFO  - Load module settings
18:38:48.088 INFO  - Loading rules...
18:38:49.460 INFO  - Loading rules done: 1372 ms
18:38:49.492 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
18:38:49.585 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-08-08)
18:38:49.601 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-07-09, analysis of 2014-08-08 18:05:54.0)
18:38:49.601 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
18:38:50.131 INFO  - Base dir: D:\Projects\ivserver\trunk\src\cg
18:38:50.131 INFO  - Working dir: D:\Projects\ivserver\trunk\src\.sonar\com.infovista_ivserver_cg
18:38:50.131 INFO  - Source dirs: D:\Projects\ivserver\trunk\src\cg
18:38:50.131 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
18:38:50.131 INFO  - Index files
18:38:50.162 INFO  - Excluded sources: 
18:38:50.162 INFO  -   **/*.vspscc
18:38:50.162 INFO  -   **/*.sh
18:38:51.972 INFO  - 653 files indexed
18:38:58.867 INFO  - Quality profile for c++: Default C++ Profile
18:38:59.507 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
18:38:59.522 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 15 ms
18:38:59.522 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
18:38:59.522 INFO  - SonarBridgeEngine is used for c++
18:38:59.538 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
18:39:04.202 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 4680 ms
18:39:04.202 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
18:39:04.218 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 16 ms
18:39:04.218 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
18:39:04.249 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 31 ms
18:39:04.249 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
18:39:04.249 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 0 ms
18:39:04.249 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
18:39:04.280 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 31 ms
18:39:04.858 INFO  - Execute decorators...
```

What am I missing?

Here is my project file:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.acme:orange
sonar.projectName=Orange Juice
sonar.projectVersion=trunk

sonar.modules=cg,ct,lg,sv,install,java
sonar.sources=.
install.sonar.sources=src
java.sonar.sources=app/api, app/cli

sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=target/cppcheck/report.xml
sonar.cxx.cppncss.reportPath=target/cppncss/report.xml
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.path=D:/CppCheck/cppcheck.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a step forward by forcing the language for each module (see below).
The Metrics are now computed correctly.

My remaining problem is that the C++ issues are not reported as they used to be, I only get the ones for Java (is the relative path to reports wrongly interpreted in case of several modules?)

```
sonar.projectKey=com.acme:orange
sonar.projectName=Orange Juice
sonar.projectVersion=trunk

sonar.modules=cg,ct,lg,sv,install,java
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=c++
java.sonar.language=java
install.sonar.language=java
install.sonar.sources=src
java.sonar.sources=app/api, app/cli

sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=target/cppcheck/report.xml
sonar.cxx.cppncss.reportPath=target/cppncss/report.xml
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.path=D:/CppCheck/cppcheck.exe
```